# Reduce query execution time in MongoDB when querying tags in an array

Tags: mongodb, bigdata, pymongo

My MongoDB collection (one of many) currently stores over 30 million documents with a total size  of 40GB. It's expected to grow to over 100 million records. I'm worried that the RAM limit will be reached soon and we will have to look into sharding or other techniques. Sometimes the documents need post-processing by the programming language (in this case Python).

It is very important for the collection to have as fast queries as possible. I monitor the free monitoring tool from MongoDB and majority of queries have an average read execution time of over 300ms which is far from optimal.

The collection has a compound index and the documents are indexed on:

- an array of tags (mandatory for the query)
- 4-5 optional single value fields (which when used, do speed up the execution)

My worry is that tags might not be selective enough. Each document can have between around 5 and 25 tags. There are hundreds of combinations of the tags which I thought would make the queries much more efficient than they actually are.

Execution stats on just the tags show a very slow query:

```
 "executionStats" : {
                "executionSuccess" : true,
                "nReturned" : 3737324,
                "executionTimeMillis" : 22600,
                "totalKeysExamined" : 3737324,
                "totalDocsExamined" : 3737324,
```

Input stage confirms that index was used:

```
"inputStage" : {
                                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                "nReturned" : 3737324,
                                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 954,
                                "works" : 3737325,
                                "advanced" : 3737324,
                                "needTime" : 0,
                                "needYield" : 0,
                                "saveState" : 29199,
                                "restoreState" : 29199,
                                "isEOF" : 1,
```

yet the results are still unsatisfactory.

Steps taken to try to reduce execution time:

- Only necessary fields are projected which reduced the time by 10-30% depending on the query
- Tried to reduce the size of each document to only contain necessary and non-empty fields
- Tried to make tags more selective

What are some other strategies that I could take to speed up the execution and try to get read time under 100ms as recommended by the monitoring tool?
Some ideas that I've had:

- Split tags into their own, separate collections
- Use aggregate instead of find to limit the number of documents returned to avoid post-processing
- Have a collection of only tags in one collection and information about each document in another but that would cause thousands or millions of separate calls by ID to the information collection

Query is rather simple and looks like this:

`db.collection.find({ tags: { $all: [tag1, tag2, tag3] }, optional_value: 1, optional_value: 2})`

Python code analyzes all of the records returned to print out reports based on data. Some of the fields analyzed could be:

- actions taken by the user that fit the specified filter
- user profile fits the specified filter (users stored in a different collection, a list of them matching the criteria is aggregated and then the document's user is compared with the list of matching profile user names in python code - room for improvement there although it only adds 10-20% overhead to the query time)
- user age fits the specified filter (one of the optional values in a query)

Comment: what does your find query look like? to me it seems like `"nReturned" : 3737324` is the problem. does python really have to do post-processing on that many records in a single query? maybe store the data in an already processed state. it's really hard to come up with a good answer without seeing what your schema and python code looks like.

Comment: I added some information about the query. Would you suggest trying to cut down the number of returned documents by pre-processing as much data as possible?

Comment: i think your goal should be to delegate as much application logic as possible to mongodb. the aggregation framework is quite capable of performing a lot of that. [on-demand materialized views](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/materialized-views/index.html) could be a way to go. performing a basic filter with just tags alone and then downloading thousands of records into python memory is bound to be slow.